# How to convert a single key value pair object to array of objects with key value pair?

Tags: javascript

I have a single object of key-value pair every key has an array as a value, How to convert it to an array of objects with key-value pair property by comparing it with another array of object.

```
var keys = [];

for (var k in obj) keys.push(k);
```

Input:

```
obj =  {
          "name": "jack",
          "age": 10,
          "country": "india",
          "state": "Delhi"
        }
        obj2 = [{key: "product", type:"", value:"", required:"true", mandatory:"true"},
        {key: "sub-product", type:"", value:"", required:"true", mandatory:"true"},
        {key: "name", type:"text", value:"", required:"true", mandatory:"true"},
        {key: "age", type:"text", value:"[0-9]", required:"true", mandatory:"true"},
        {key: "country", type:"text", value:"[a-z]", required:"true", mandatory:"true"},
        {key: "state", type:"text", value:"[a-z]", required:"true", mandatory:"true"}]
```

Expected output:

```
result = [{key: "name", type:"text", value:"", required:"true", mandatory:"true",setValue:"jack"},
        {key: "age", type:"text", value:"[0-9]", required:"true", mandatory:"true",setValue:"10"},
        {key: "country", type:"text", value:"[a-z]", required:"true", mandatory:"true",setValue:"india"},
        {key: "state", type:"text", value:"[a-z]", required:"true", mandatory:"true",setValue:"Delhi"}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter it first using `hasOwnProperty` and then map it to set `setValue` property. Here is implementation:

```js
var obj = { "name": "jack", "age": 10, "country": "india", "state": "Delhi" };
var obj2 =[{key: "product", type:"", value:"", required:"true", mandatory:"true"}, {key: "sub-product", type:"", value:"", required:"true", mandatory:"true"}, {key: "name", type:"text", value:"", required:"true", mandatory:"true"}, {key: "age", type:"text", value:"[0-9]", required:"true", mandatory:"true"}, {key: "country", type:"text", value:"[a-z]", required:"true", mandatory:"true"}, {key: "state", type:"text", value:"[a-z]", required:"true", mandatory:"true"}];


var result = obj2.filter(k=>obj.hasOwnProperty(k.key)).map(p=>({...p, setValue:obj[p.key]}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over `obj2`. If the `key` value is a property of `obj`, copy the corresponding value into the `setValue` property of the object, and push it onto the result.

```js
obj = {
  "name": "jack",
  "age": 10,
  "country": "india",
  "state": "Delhi"
};
obj2 = [{key: "product", type="", value="", required="true", mandatory="true"},
        {key: "sub-product", type="", value="", required="true", mandatory="true"},
        {key: "name", type="text", value="", required="true", mandatory="true"},
        {key: "age", type="text", value="[0-9]", required="true", mandatory="true"},
        {key: "country", type="text", value="[a-z]", required="true", mandatory="true"},
        {key: "state", type="text", value="[a-z]", required="true", mandatory="true"}];

var result = [];
obj2.forEach(o => {
  if (o.key in obj) {
    o.setValue = obj[o.key];
    result.push(o);
  }
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.flatmap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to achieve this

```js
const obj = {
  "name": "jack",
  "age": 10,
  "country": "india",
  "state": "Delhi"
}
const obj2 = [
  {key: "product", type:"", value:"", required:"true", mandatory:"true"},
  {key: "sub-product", type:"", value:"", required:"true", mandatory:"true"},
  {key: "name", type:"text", value:"", required:"true", mandatory:"true"},
  {key: "age", type:"text", value:"[0-9]", required:"true", mandatory:"true"},
  {key: "country", type:"text", value:"[a-z]", required:"true", mandatory:"true"},
  {key: "state", type:"text", value:"[a-z]", required:"true", mandatory:"true"}
]

const result = obj2.flatMap((entry) => {
  if (obj[entry.key]) {
    return {
      ...entry,
            setValue: obj[entry.key],
    }
  }
    return []
})

console.log(result)
```