# remove an object from array based on key not value?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of the object where I want to remove an object based on key? I tried with filter, omit in lodash but nothing worked. the description can be in any position

Input

```
input = [{product: "abc", value: "123"},{name: "def", value: "234"},{description: ["abd123"]}]
```

Expected Output

```
output = [{product: "abc", value: "123"},{name: "def", value: "234"}]

const result = input.filter(el => el.key !== description)
```

Comment: What's `key` supposed to be? You object structure is weird. You have an array of objects where each one is different? This is unusual at best...

Comment: i should remove object in having key as description

Comment: `el => !el.hasOwnProperty('description')`…?

Comment: you seem to have asked this question (or [variations of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64040344/how-to-convert-a-single-key-value-pair-object-to-array-of-objects-with-key-value)) multiple times now.

Comment: hi @Liam when ur stuck for 2-3 hours we depend on stackoverflow. I think all the quetion I raised are different, sorry if there was a repeatition

Comment: Maybe it's time to spend some time understanding js object structures? Give a man a fish, etc.

Comment: sure @Liam... but sometimes ur stuck in an issue which is very very simple, only understand when u get the solution.... anyways thank you soo much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd declare array this way:

```
const input = [{product: "abc", value: "123"},{name: "def", value:"234"},{description: ["abd123"]}];
```

and delete your object using some function as

```
let output = input.filter(object => !object.hasOwnProperty("description"));
```

so that

```
output = [{product: "abc", value: "123"},{name: "def", value:"234"}];
```

```js
const input = [{product: "abc", value: "123"},{name: "def", value:"234"},{description: ["abd123"]}];

let output = input.filter(object => !object.hasOwnProperty("description"));

output = [{product: "abc", value: "123"},{name: "def", value:"234"}];

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you would like to remove any object has key use hasOwnProperty to check

```
let input = [{product: "abc", value: "123"},{name: "def", value: "234",description:0},{description: ["abd123"]}]


let output = input.filter(el=> !el.hasOwnProperty('description'))
```

Answer (score -3):

You can do it like this:

`input.filter(el=> !el.description)`

Comment: What about `{product:abc", value: "123"}`?

Comment: this won't work if el.description = false or null or undefined or 0

Comment: el => !el.hasOwnProperty('description')

Comment: He is looking to find those that don't have description property, yes, el.hasOwn... is going to work, I just put another option there